# Put php file in the background on Linux

Tags: php, linux, background, nohup

I have a PHP file that checks if a field in MySQL database is empty.
If the field is empty, PHP is an update.
I want to color this file in the background on Linux.
If a user creates a record, the PHP file in the background will be updated.
My PHP code:

```
<?php
$mysqli = mysqli_connect("localhost","name","pass","database");
$query = 'UPDATE  users SET  permissions =  "content" WHERE permissions = ""';
$n = $mysqli->query($query);
$query = "SELECT * from users";
$result = $mysqli->query($query);
$row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
$subdominio = $row["name"];
$created_at = $row["created_at"];
?>
```

How can I do this?
I can have problem with it file PHP in the background on Linux? Performance, slow down and etc?

Thanks very much!

Comment: It would be a better idea to fix whatever code is not setting the `permissions` column correctly.

Comment: do you want to run it as a background process? (eg. daemon) or initiate it in a particular event. If you want to trigger it on an event? who or what will initiate it? will it be initiated from your website ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Create PHP file and put your code there. (For example **myfile.php**)
2. Install '`screen`' :

Ubuntu & Debian: `apt-get -y install screen`

CentOS & Fedora: `yum -y install screen`

**** Follow steps 3 & 4 to execute myfile.php all the time. And follow steps 5 & 6 to execute myfile.php every 1 minute or every X time using crontab. ****

3. Type ' `screen` ' .
4. Type ' `php myfile.php` ' .
   And minimize/hide it by pressing `Ctrl + A + D`.
   And get back to it by typing ' `screen -r` ' .
5. Type ' `crontab -e` ' .
6. To execute every minute, you can type ' `* * * * * php myfile.php` ' ... If you don't want every minute, Google about crontab.

Comment: No problem @Julio Mac !

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to launch any program in the background by using the & symbol in Linux:

```
php myscript.php &
```

To see that it is running you use:

```
jobs
```

It will list a number for the job so you can call it back to the foreground to interact/kill it:

```
fg 1
```

F.Y.I If your script prints anything you will want to redirect output or it will go to the console

Comment: John Morrison, thanks very much!
I understand your command, but the command posted by protld help me!
Good Lucky! :)